# Keep a console app running in loop for windows service when there is a new row with a particular column value inserted

Tags: c#, sql, .net, windows-services, console-application

I am working to crete a console app to be run by a windows service, my goal is to check a particular column value in SQL, if it's zero (0) then my app would send a notification and marks it to one(1).
I am using entity framework to fetch the database values and using entity.table.where clause to filter the values. Can someone please tell me how to keep it running in loop for a windows service?

```
var list = dbEntity.MyTable.Where(e => e.ColumnValue == 0).ToList();
if(list.Any())
{
  //my logic here
}
```

Comment: `while(true) { // your code here }`

Comment: rather than keeping the application always on, why you don't just do it from database level with CLR function or store procedure ? you can create a trigger on that column, if changed then execute the CLR function or store procedure (if the action will be outside the SQL (e.g. send a notification to different app). if the action is inside the database, then there is no need for CLR function, just do it internally.

Comment: there is a handy little tool called Top Shelf (http://topshelf-project.com/) that makes it really easy to convert console apps into constantly running windows services.

Comment: Is new FileSystemWatcher(my local path) or Sqldependency an option here?

Answer (score 0):

Best thing I have discovered is to use TopShelf and use Hostfactory and Timer for continuous service run.